# Why CSS Media query for width of table-rows not working?

Tags: html, css, html-table, media-queries

This is my code, I want to reduce the width of all the rows in table (except for first table) when the size of screen is more than 1000px. I tried this but this media query is not seem to be working. And also I want the bottom border of the table to be rounded, with the code I tried except for the left-most all the border-bottom radius is getting rounded
Can anyone tell what I am missing?
I have read many answers none of them seem to be working

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .table-container {
    float: left;
    width: 15%;
  }
  .table-container:first-of-type {
    width: 40%;
  }
}

.table_container {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

.container::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

table {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

tr {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

td {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px double white;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: grey;
  width: 272px;
}

.sub_text {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #0071ce;
  font-weight: 100;
}

th {
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 70px;
}

.header {
  color: #0071ce;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px;
}

.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

table tr:last-child td:first-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

table tr:last-child td:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px
```

```html
<div class="table_container">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2">Cost</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                </thead>

                <td class="header" rowspan="4">Your cost per biweekly paycheck<br>
                    <span class="sub_text">Tobacco-free rates shown</span>
                </td>
                <td> emp Only</td>
                <tr>
                    <td> emp + Spouse/partner</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> emp + child(ren)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> emp + family</td>
                </tr>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="header" rowspan="2"> Org’s annual max contribution<br>
                        <span class="sub_text">
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td> emp Only</td>
                <tr>
                    <td> emp + dependent(s)</td>
                </tr>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="header" rowspan="2">Annua deductible<br>
                        <span class="sub_text">in-network care</span>
                    </td>
                    <td> emp Only</td>
                <tr>
                    <td> emp + dependent(s)</td>
                </tr>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </div>
<div class="table_container">
  <table id="table2" class="checkboxdiv">
    <tr>
      <th>Tab B<input type="checkbox" id="2" name="table2" value="table2"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>D</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>E</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>F</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>G</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>H</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="table_container">
  <table id="table2" class="checkboxdiv">
    <tr>
      <th>Tab B<input type="checkbox" id="2" name="table2" value="table2"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>D</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>E</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>F</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>G</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>H</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="table_container">
  <table id="table2" class="checkboxdiv">
    <tr>
      <th>Tab B<input type="checkbox" id="2" name="table2" value="table2"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>D</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>E</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>F</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>G</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>H</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

```js
    @media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
                
            .table-container {
                float: left;
                width: 15%;
            }
        }
```

Comment: tried it, still not working

Comment: media queries should always be below the basic rules of the css. look it - https://jsfiddle.net/max_max/csj5ftnu/1/

Comment: Could you please help with the border-bottom of the left most table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were using .table-container, not .table_container from above. Just tried this and it works as expected. Also make sure to add it to the bottom of the stylesheet.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
        .table_container {
            float: left;
            width: 15%;
        }

        .table_container:first-of-type() {
            width: 40%;
            
        }
    }
```

For the bottom-border-radius, if you're trying to avoid using classes this is a solution that works if your table is staying the same size. If you add columns you would have to adjust tr:nth-of-type(7) to the appropriate number.

```
table tr:last-child td:first-child {
border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px
}

.table_container:nth-of-type(1) tr:last-child td:first-child {
border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}

.table_container:nth-of-type(1) tr:nth-of-type(7) td:first-child {
border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Could you please help with the border-bottom of the left most table